# i cannot insert my data of php form into mysql ?? my code is following?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
include 'db.php';

$serial= $_POST['serial'];
$date_of_reg = $_POST['date_of_reg'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$doc_type = $_POST['doc_type'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (serial,date_of_reg,name,doc_type) VALUES ('$serial','$date_of_reg','$name', '$doc_type');";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if ($result == false) {
    include "src/header.php";
    include "src/mainmenu.php";
    echo '<p>Error: cannot execute query</p>';
    echo '<p><a href="register.php">Try again</a></p>';
    include "src/footer.php";
    exit;
}
else {
    header('Location: private.php');
}

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: what is the error bhai?

Comment: too many unknowns. check for errors, there's bound to be something wrong somewhere

Comment: [**guess what you're using**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

Comment: Also ensure you sanitize your inputs before putting them into the query

Comment: when i try to add data into 'serial'  from form it shows me empty row in mysql. i set type of 'serial' as 'text'

Comment: @ssnobody yeah... `name` too and have added that to my answer, but have stated in there that I've seen many use "name" without ticking it and with no issues, including myself. Most baffingly bizarre. +1 on your comment.

Answer (score 4):

You're assuming success without checking for errors, which by doing that, would have signaled a syntax error to the effect of:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'serial

while using `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` in your code.

Being the use of a MySQL reserved word, being `serial` (edit) and `name`, but strangely enough, many have used that (name) without issues, myself included which baffles me.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Either rename it to "serials" which is safe to use, or wrap it in ticks:

```
INSERT INTO clients (`serial`, date_of_reg, `name`, doc_type)
```

Full line rewrite:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (`serial`,date_of_reg, `name`, doc_type)  
        VALUES ('$serial','$date_of_reg','$name', '$doc_type');";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
```

You should also escape your data, should your inputted data contain anything that MySQL may complain about also.

**For example:** James O'Neil will cause an issue with the apostrophe. Escape it:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

*...as you should for all your inputs.*

Plus, in regards to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) which is something you are open to,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Should you get a deprecation notice, you will see what you'll have to do; switch to MySQLi or PDO, which you should do anyway, since it will be removed from future PHP release.
*Be ahead of the game*.

---

Footnotes:

Since you're using a form which is something you didn't post, make sure that it does use a POST method and that all inputs have the "name" attributes for them and with no typos. *An insight*.

I.e.:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="serial">
...
</form>
```

etc.

**Edit:**

as per a link you left for your form:

`<input type="text" name="name" id="serial" />`

That should read as `<input type="text" name="serial" id="serial" />` you used "name" instead of "serial", and error reporting would have spotted that.

Then `<input type="text" name="name" id="date_of_reg" />` again, using the wrong name attribute for it, being "name".

```
<input type="text" name="date_of_reg" id="date_of_reg" />
```

You cannot rely on "id" alone.

---

**Connection:**

Plus, since we don't know which MySQL API you're connecting with, make sure that it is in fact `mysql_` and not `mysqli_` or PDO, since you need to use the same from connection to query.

- Those different APIs do **not** intermix.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: **You're assuming success** would have been enough text.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen true ;-)

Comment: this is my register.php  :- http://textuploader.com/a5pmd

Comment: @KartikChaudhari huh? are you trying to drop code in comments?

Comment: @KartikChaudhari copy my code **exactly** as shown. Those are not regular quotes `'` but ticks `\`` which resembles quotes but are **not** the same. either do that, or rename your column to "serials" in plural form.

Comment: register.php :- http://textuploader.com/a5pmd  .             register_action.php :-  http://textuploader.com/a5pml

Comment: for one thing `<input type="text" name="name" id="serial" />` that should read as `<input type="text" name="serial" id="serial" />` you used "name" instead of "serial", and error reporting would have spotted that @KartikChaudhari

Comment: A a note, `name` is also a reserved word so should also be backticked

Comment: @ssnobody yes I saw your comment under OP's question where I replied but you deleted it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Yup, apologies for altering the record but I thought it was more appropriate on the answer already referencing the reserved words.

Comment: @ssnobody No worries, *cheers*

Comment: @KartikChaudhari I've made a few edits since you first saw my answer and have spotted a few more errors you made. Reload it and read it carefully and in its entirety. Use error reporting and error checking on your query as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You have way more patience than me to write such answers :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Remember, I grow cactus ;-)